# Best way to store inheritance type configuration in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, configuration, jsonschema

I store four different variations of configuration in mongo as a nested document.

1. default configuration
2. environment specific configuration.
3. site specific configuration.
4. page specific configuration.

Precedence : default < environment < site < page.
The configuration which has greater precedence can override the fields in the lower configuration.

For example : 
default configuration:

```
{
 "a":{
   "b":"c"
  }
 "default":{
   }
}
```

Env configuration:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b":"c" 
  }
}
```

Site configuration:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b":"c"
  }
}
```

Page configuration:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b":"c"
  }
}
```

So, whenever a configuration for a page is requested i have to query all four documents and merge them.

This would be the merged document if a configuration for a page is requested:

```
{
  "a":{
    "b":"c"
  },
  "default": {
  }
}
```

So, if my page is requested a million times, then for each page requested i should fetch all four documents and merge based on their precedence.

How to best store this type of data,how can i remove four db calls for every page load.Is there a better way to store such configuration data?

Comment: Hi @simplyblue did you solve this problem ?

Comment: @kimathie No :(